# ASP.Net MVC DisplayFormat DataFormatString show unit of measurment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that when a ASP.Net MVC applicaion model has a cost property decorated like this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

Then on the view I display

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cost )
```

Ill get a label with with the currency symbol then the cost.

But I was wondering could it be used for unit of mesurment so the

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm}")]
public decimal Size{ get; set; }
```

Then on the view I display

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Size)
```

Gives 55 mm

Comment: Not sure how ASP.Net MVC interprets the format string, but may just using  `"{0} mm"` for the format?

Comment: can that unit of measure change?  why not store it in a separate field in your model as an enum.

Comment: Kelly that is the answer, never tried it out of the currly braces, can you re post you comment as a answer and I will mark it as the answer, so people in the future can find it.

Comment: Fran, the unit of measurement the size are always in mm in this system.  There is other fields that have differnet units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the `DataFormatString` would be used for input to a `String.Format` in some fashion, so changing `"{0:mm}"` to `"{0} mm"` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} mm")] wast it